# xarray Dataset resize coordinates in dimension for to_zarr()

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, python-xarray, zarr

I have a dataset and wish to append it to an existing zarr and I must handle that one dimension in the dataset, 'range', is of different size than in the zarr. I'm hoping to just pad data with zeros or nan.

## The problem

Here is what happens when I try to append some new data to my zarr:

```
>>> z = zarr.open('my.zarr', 'r+')
>>> ds = ... # created from other files
>>> ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:            (range: 12571, time: 70)
Coordinates:
  * time               (ping_time) datetime64[ns] 2022-05-05T12:50:43.625000 ...
  * range              (range) float64 0.0 1.0 2.0 ... 1.267e+04 1.267e+04
  ...
Data variables:
    mydata             (time, range) float64 7.379...
    ...
>>> z.range.size
12669
>>> ds.to_zarr('my.zarr', append_dim='time') # Problem!!
...
ValueError: variable 'mydata' already exists with different dimension sizes: {'range': 12669} != {'range': 12571}. to_zarr() only supports changing dimension sizes when explicitly appending, but append_dim='time'
```

From this it seems like it might work if only I can change the 'range' dimension so that of the existing zarr:

```
>>> ds.range.size
12571
>>>
```

to

```
>>> ds.range.size
12669
>>>
```

How can I change the size of the coordinates of an existing dimension in the Dataset?
Is there another way to append this data to my zarr?

## What I've tried:

After looking around on how to append my 'range' dimension I've tried to assign new coordinates, by creating a new dimension and renaming back and forth, but it does not seem to work:

```
>>>ds = ds.rename({"range":"old_range"})
>>>ds = ds.expand_dims(dim={"range" : z.range.size})
>>>res = np.append(ds.old_range.data, z.range[ds.old_range.data.size : z.range.size])
>>>ds = ds.assign_coords({"range": res})
>>>ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:            (range: 12669, time: 70,
                        old_range: 12571)
Coordinates:
  * time          (ping_time) datetime64[ns] 2022-05-05T12:50:43.625000 ...
  * old_range          (old_range) float64 0.0 0.007955 0.01591 ... 99.98 99.99
  * range              (range) float64 0.0 0.007955 0.01591 ... 99.98 99.99
Data variables:
    mydata                 (range, time, old_range) float64 7.379...
```

So it seems like ´mydata´ now has both dimensions. And it seems like 'range' dimension has been added to all data variables. How can I fix/avoid this?

By the way, for the revese case where `ds.range.size > z.range.size` it seems to work to just do `z.range.resize(ds.range.size)`

Answer (score 0):

After some more googling I found something that seems to work.
The xarray 'pad' function works to resize the 'range' dimension like this:

```
amountToPad = z.range.size - ds.range.size
ds = ds.pad(range=(0,amountToPad))
ds.to_zarr('my.zarr', append_dim='time')
```